# Toolbar hamburger interfering with back arrow button

Tags: java, android

I'm seting a drawer with an hamburger, when I open a fragment I want to remove the hamburger and replace it with an arrow that calls `onBackPressed()`.

What's happening is the hamburger gets replaced by the arrow, but the listener on the arrow doesn't get called. If I remove the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` completely it will work. How can I fix this?

**Opening the new fragment:**

```
    Fragment_Subjects frag = new Fragment_Subjects();
    fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.mainContainer, frag)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

**Seting the drawer toggle:**

```
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close); //back arrow works when this line is removed
    assert drawer != null;
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

**Back arrow listener:**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**onBackPressed:**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)){
        drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Override `onBackPressed()` and call `finish()` then try.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: You can also try `toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(view -> onBackPressed())`

Comment: Thanks that worked, feel free to write an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              onBackPressed();
        }
 });
```